# Problemas ao atribuir valores para variáveis em um objeto

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, parâmetros, fila

Estou precisando passar dados de variáveis para outra classe chamada Fila.java. Lá tenho um vetor do tipo que recebe objetos, então na classe principal criei um objeto que inicializei da seguinte forma :

```
public class Dados{
    int menu = 20,i=0; 
    String produto;
    int Quantidade=0;
    float ValorUn=0,Desconto=0,AliquotaICMS=0;
    String Obs;     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
        BancoDeDados db = null;
        Dados da = new Dados;
        da.menu = 20;
}
```

Porém intendente da forma que eu inicialize ele, gera erro na hora de compilar

Se eu inicializo assim :

```
Dados da;
```

Ele diz que a variável não foi inicializada, se atribuo o valor **NULL**, diz que está apontando para um ponteiro nulo, como resolver?

```
Classe Fila.java        
public class Fila {
    public Fila() {     

    }

    int inicio, fim, numelem,tamanho;
    Object array[];
    String elem;//string

    Fila(int tam){
        this.inicio = 0;
        this.fim = 0;
        this.numelem = 0;
        this.tamanho=tam;
        this.array = new Object[tam];
    }

    public boolean vazia(){
       if(numelem==0)
           return true;
           return false;    
    }

    public void inserir(Object elem){       
        array[fim]=elem;
        numelem++;
        fim++;
        if(fim==tamanho)
        fim=0;
        System.out.println(array[0]);
    }
    public Object remover(){
        Object temp=null;
        if(!vazia()){
            temp=array[inicio];
            array[inicio]=null;
            inicio++;
            numelem--;
            if(inicio==tamanho)
                inicio=0;
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Fila vazia");
        return temp;
    }


    public void AumentarVetor() {       
        tamanho = (tamanho/2)*3;                
    }                               
}
```

Classe Main :

```
import BancoDeDados.Dados;

public class Main {

    public static class Dados{

        int menu = 20,i=0; 
        String produto;
        int Quantidade=0;
        float ValorUn=0,Desconto=0,AliquotaICMS=0;
        String Obs;

        public Dados(){
              //também á uma boa idéia inicializar os valores das variáveis dentro do construtor
            }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        //BancoDeDados db = null;
        //BancoDeDados.main(args);
        Dados da = new Dados();
        da.menu = 20;
        da.produto = "Teste";
        Fila f = new Fila();

        da.menu = 10;

        f.inserir(da);              
    }
}
```

Comment: Você deve descrever o erro obtido ao compilar. Note que, aparentemente seu código está errado. O método mais está fora da classe. Aparentemente disperso no arquivo.

Comment: Boa noite, Ele mostra seguinte mensagem : "The local variable da may not have been initialized. "  Porém não sei como eu deveria inicializar ela.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa criar um método construtor, os construtores são os responsáveis por criar o objeto em memória, ou seja, instanciar a classe que foi definida. Eles são obrigatórios e são declarados dessa forma:

```
public class Dados{

    int menu = 20, i = 0; 
    String produto;
    int quantidade = 0;
    float valorUn = 0, desconto = 0, aliquotaICMS = 0;
    String obs;

    public Dados(){
        //também é uma boa idéia inicializar os valores das variáveis dentro do construtor
    }
}
```

Uma classe pode ter vários construtores e eles podem receber nenhum ou vários parâmetros, e na classe `main` você deve instanciar o objeto assim:

```
Dados da = new Dados();
```

Comment: Parte do problema foi resolvido, muito obrigado.

Agora ele da erro ao inserir na fila

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Fila.inserir(Fila.java:40)
 at Main.main(Main.java:36)

Comment: como está o código da classe Fila?

Comment: Acrescentei a classe na descrição do problema.

Comment: "você precisa criar um método construtor", "Eles são obrigatórios" não é inteiramente verdade. Não é obrigatório definir um construtor, pois o compilador irá criar um sem parâmetros se nenhum for definido.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos partir o problema em partes.

1. A classe `BancoDeDados` não é relevante para o problema. Nada é feito com ela no Main. 
   Assim, o problema está nas 2 linhas seguintes:

Código com erro:

```
Dados da = new Dados;
da.menu = 20;
```

2. A classe Dados é inicializada como `Dados da = new Dados();` Há um erro de sintaxe. Assumo ainda que a classe `Dados` tem apenas 1 construtor, o construtor vazio (sem argumentos).

Algures no código da classe Dados, assumo existir:

```
public Dados()
{
    /*Faz alguma coisa aqui? Talvez aqui inicialize a Fila?*/
}
```

3. Confirme que a Fila é inicializada com o construtor correto. `Fila testeFila = new Fila(5);`. Tenha atenção que `new Fila(5);` chama o construtor de 1 argumento:

O construtor que criou:

```
Fila(int tam){
    this.inicio = 0;
    this.fim = 0;
    this.numelem = 0;
    this.tamanho = tam;
    this.array = new Object[tam];
}
```

Se chamar `Fila testeFila = new Fila();`, o construtor chamado é:

```
public Fila() {
}
```

E o `array` não é inicializado.

---

Algum destes passos era o problema?

---

`Fila` é uma Classe. Esta classe tem um campo `Object array[];`.

Este objecto não é inicializado por default. A linha que o instancia está no construtor:

```
Fila(int tam){
    this.inicio = 0;
    this.fim = 0;
    this.numelem = 0;
    this.tamanho = tam;
    **this.array = new Object[tam];**
}
```

Ou seja, é necessário que o código chegue a esta linha para que o objecto `array` seja inicializado.

`Fila(int tam)` é um Construtor da classe `Fila`. Recebe como parâmetro um inteiro, e executa as 5 linhas de código que estão no excerto acima.

No seu Main, declara a fila como

```
Fila f = new Fila();
```

Isto não vai chamar o construtor que criou acima, mas o **construtor vazio**.

Ainda na sua classe `Fila`:

```
public Fila() {     
        /*Este é o código que executa ao invocar Fila f = new Fila();*/
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde,  
Coloquei a classe Main na descrição do problema, o problema está sendo que não consigo inserir no array como demonstrado na Main. Obs : Sim, tem um construtor vazio.

Comment: Então parte do problema é a instanciação da Fila. Vou editar um pouco a resposta para clareza; veja o ponto 3.